# Getting error TS2307: Cannot find module when using rollup in typescript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rollupjs

I am getting the following error after generating a bundle with [rollupjs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) and running `npx tsc lib/index.d.ts` to check the result:

```
 error TS2307: Cannot find module '@solana/web3.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

import {PublicKey} from '@solana/web3.js';
```

My code example is very simple, just importing a PublicKey:

```
// src/index.ts
import {PublicKey} from '@solana/web3.js';

const a = new PublicKey("SOME_KEY");
```

This is my current `rollup.config.js`configuration:

```
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import {terser} from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const extensions = ['.js', '.ts'];

const ignoredDependencies = [
  '@solana/web3.js',
];

const globals = {
  '@bundlr-network/client': 'client',
  'filereader-stream': 'fileReaderStream',
};

function generateConfig(configType, format) {
  const browser = configType === 'browser' || configType === 'react-native';
  const bundle = format === 'iife';

  const config = {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    plugins: [
      alias({
        entries: [
          {
            find: /^\./, // Relative paths.
            replacement: '.',
            async customResolver(source, importer, options) {
              const resolved = await this.resolve(source, importer, {
                skipSelf: true,
                ...options,
              });
              if (resolved == null) {
                return;
              }
              const {id: resolvedId} = resolved;
              const directory = path.dirname(resolvedId);
              const moduleFilename = path.basename(resolvedId);
              const forkPath = path.join(
                directory,
                '__forks__',
                configType,
                moduleFilename,
              );
              const hasForkCacheKey = `has_fork:${forkPath}`;
              let hasFork = this.cache.get(hasForkCacheKey);
              if (hasFork === undefined) {
                hasFork = fs.existsSync(forkPath);
                this.cache.set(hasForkCacheKey, hasFork);
              }
              if (hasFork) {
                return forkPath;
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      }),
      commonjs(),
      nodeResolve({
        browser,
        dedupe: ['bn.js', 'buffer'],
        extensions,
        preferBuiltins: !browser,
      }),
      babel({
        exclude: '**/node_modules/**',
        extensions,
        babelHelpers: bundle ? 'bundled' : 'runtime',
        plugins: bundle ? [] : ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
      }),
      replace({
        preventAssignment: true,
        values: {
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env),
          'process.env.BROWSER': JSON.stringify(browser),
          'process.env.npm_package_version': JSON.stringify(
            process.env.npm_package_version,
          ),
        },
      }),
    ],
    onwarn: function (warning, rollupWarn) {
      rollupWarn(warning);
      if (warning.code === 'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY') {
        throw new Error(
          'Please eliminate the circular dependencies listed ' +
            'above and retry the build',
        );
      }
    },
    treeshake: {
      moduleSideEffects: false,
    },
  };

  if (!browser) {
    // Prevent dependencies from being bundled
    config.external = ignoredDependencies;
  }

  switch (configType) {
    case 'browser':
    case 'react-native':
      switch (format) {
        case 'iife': {
          config.external = ['http', 'https', 'node-fetch'].concat(
            ignoredDependencies,
          );

          config.output = [
            {
              file: 'lib/index.iife.js',
              format: 'iife',
              name: 'myproject',
              sourcemap: true,
              globals: globals,
            },
            {
              file: 'lib/index.iife.min.js',
              format: 'iife',
              name: 'myproject',
              sourcemap: true,
              plugins: [terser({mangle: false, compress: false})],
              globals: globals,
            },
          ];

          break;
        }
        default: {
          config.output = [
            {
              file: `lib/index.${
                configType === 'react-native' ? 'native' : 'browser.cjs'
              }.js`,
              format: 'cjs',
              sourcemap: true,
            },
            configType === 'browser'
              ? {
                  file: 'lib/index.browser.esm.js',
                  format: 'es',
                  sourcemap: true,
                }
              : null,
          ].filter(Boolean);

          // Prevent dependencies from being bundled
          config.external = ignoredDependencies;

          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    case 'node':
      config.output = [
        {
          file: 'lib/index.cjs.js',
          format: 'cjs',
          sourcemap: true,
        },
        {
          file: 'lib/index.esm.js',
          format: 'es',
          sourcemap: true,
        },
      ];
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown configType: ${configType}`);
  }

  return config;
}

export default [
  generateConfig('node'),
  generateConfig('browser'),
  generateConfig('browser', 'iife'),
  generateConfig('react-native'),
];
```

and my `tsconfig.json` configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext" ,
    'Fragment'. */
    "module": "esnext" ,
    "moduleResolution": "node" ,
    "baseUrl": "src" ,
    "paths": {} ,
    "resolveJsonModule": true ,
    "allowJs": true ,
    "declaration": true ,
    "declarationDir": "declarations" ,
    "isolatedModules": true ,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true ,
    "esModuleInterop": true ,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true ,
    "strict": true ,
    "noUnusedLocals": true ,
    "noUnusedParameters": true ,
    "noImplicitReturns": true ,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true ,
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Why my library cannot find the corresponding type declarations? How or where should I add the package dependencies so running `npx tsc lib/index.d.ts` doesn't fail?